# SVG elements scale from parent class for responsiveness

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg

I'm using wordpress and I can only use CSS for the SVG elements.
I have a map of the area where I put on top the SVG elements. (I am using a random map as of now)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYEQR.png)

Now those markers are SVGs. The image of the map and the SVG elements are inside a div called 'map'.

```
<div id="map">
<img class="style-svg" id="hole1" src="http://127.0.0.69/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/Untitled-1.svg" />
<img class="style-svg" id="hole2" src="http://127.0.0.69/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/Untitled-1.svg" />
<img class="style-svg" id="hole3" src="http://127.0.0.69/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/Untitled-1.svg" />
<img class="style-svg" id="hole4" src="http://127.0.0.69/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/Untitled-1.svg" />
<img class="style-svg" id="hole5" src="http://127.0.0.69/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/Untitled-1.svg" />
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7" 
src="http://orrlakegolfclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Map.png" 
alt="test" width="650" height="812" />
</div>
```

...and this is my CSS code.

```
.style-svg {
height:90px;
z-index:10;
position:absolute;
}
#map{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#hole1 {
transform: translate(735%,100px);
}
#hole2 {
transform: translate(200px,120px);
}
#hole3 {
transform: translate(400px,250px);
}
#hole4 {
transform: translate(700px,150px);
}
#hole5 {
transform: translate(350px,100px);
}
.aligncenter.size-full.wp-image-7{
padding:0;
}
```

I want it such that it scales from the parent div if at a point it resized. My other option would've been just make the whole map static and not scale down if resized.

Comment: Why not just turn it all (ie. map and markers) into an SVG?  You can style it so it is responsive, and all will work fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention but the markers are clicked it will trigger a pop up of set of images... as each marker is represented as the holes of the course.

Comment: You can make elements in an SVG clickable.

Comment: I have done just that. Now its 1 SVG. Thank you for your suggestion kind sir